# Adding material-components-ios as a package dependency to an Xcode 11 project fails

Tags: ios, xcode11, material-components

(This is using Xcode 11.5.)

I'm trying to add [material-components-ios](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) as a package dependency to my project (via `File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency...`), pasting the github.com URL and using the version "Up to Next Major" with 109.7.0 as the current version.

I get this message:

```
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios has no Package.swift manifest for version 109.7.0
```

Which is totally true, there isn't a `Package.swift` file to be found in that release. Is there another way to install this package as a dependency for my Xcode project? Should I be using a different release? Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialise pods in your project
2. Add this line to your target (pod 'MaterialComponents','116.0.0')
3. Run `pod install` in your project's folder

Note: Choose which version of the pod you need.